# Number of ways $n$ distinct objects can be fit into $k$ distinct boxes such that every box contains at least $a$ objects and no more than $b$ objects?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, multinomial-theorem

Distribute 200 distinct students into 7 groups, where each group has no less than 25 and no more than 29 students.

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^7x_i = 200 \space \wedge (25\le x_i\le 29)$$

I started with choosing 25 students for each group $${200 \choose 25}{175 \choose 25}{150 \choose 25}{125 \choose 25}{100 \choose 25}{75 \choose 25}{50 \choose 25}*K$$

Then I have to choose the ways the rest of the people can be distributed ($K$):

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^7y_i = 25 \space \wedge (0 \le y_i \le 4) $$

What is the next step?

Comment: Your title makes no sense, since you give the same condition (“at least” and “no less than”) twice. Did you mean “at least $b$ objects and no **more** than $a$ objects”?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yeah, sorry and thank you. English isn't my first language and it somehow made sense to me when writing it.

Comment: There are only three different patterns in which to distribute the remaining $25$ students in $7$ groups, with no more than $4$ to a group.

Comment: @saulspatz groups of 4,4,4,4,4,4,1 and 4,4,4,4,4,3,2 and 4,4,4,4,3,3,3? So my $K$ would be equal to ${7 \choose 1}{25 \choose 4}{21 \choose 4}{17 \choose 4}{13 \choose 4}{9 \choose 4}{5 \choose 4} + {7 \choose 2}{25 \choose 4}{21 \choose 4}{17 \choose 4}{13 \choose 4}{9 \choose 4}{5 \choose 3}{2 \choose 2} + {7 \choose 3}{25 \choose 4}{21 \choose 4}{17 \choose 4}{13 \choose 4}{9 \choose 3}{6 \choose 3}{3 \choose 3} $?

Comment: That looks right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the multinomial theorem, the number of ways to arrange $27$ people in the first group, $28$ people in the third group, and $29$ people in each of the other groups is
$$
\frac{200!}{27!\,29!\,28!\,29!\,29!\,29!\,29!}
$$
which is the coefficient of the term
$$
200!\cdot\overset{\text{group $1$}\\}{\frac{x^{27}}{27!}}\cdot\overset{\text{group $2$}\\}{\frac{x^{29}}{29!}}\cdot\overset{\text{group $3$}\\}{\frac{x^{28}}{28!}}\cdot\overset{\text{group $4$}\\}{\frac{x^{29}}{29!}}\cdot\overset{\text{group $5$}\\}{\frac{x^{29}}{29!}}\cdot\overset{\text{group $6$}\\}{\frac{x^{29}}{29!}}\cdot\overset{\text{group $7$}\\}{\frac{x^{29}}{29!}}
$$
All similar terms are totaled in
$$
200!\left[x^{200}\right]\left(\frac{x^{25}}{25!}+\frac{x^{26}}{26!}+\cdots+\frac{x^{29}}{29!}\right)^7=3.726481552708924859\times10^{164}
$$

---

**Simpler Example**

Put $5$ students into two groups where each group has $2$ or $3$ people in it. There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways to put $2$ students in group $1$ and $3$ students in group $2$ and $\binom{5}{3}=10$ ways to put $3$ students in group $1$ and $2$ students in group $2$. That is, $20$ ways to form the groups.

Using the approach in the answer above:
$$
\begin{align}
5!\left[x^5\right]\left(\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}\right)^2
&=120\left[x^5\right]\left(\frac{x^4}4+\frac{x^5}6+\frac{x^6}{36}\right)\\
&=120\cdot\frac16\\[6pt]
&=20
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the multinomial theorem at all. How do you get from the equation to the end result?

Comment: @JustAnEuropean: the [Multinomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) is a generalization of the Binomial Theorem for more than two variables: $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)^m=\sum_{|\alpha|=m}\frac{m!}{\alpha!}x^\alpha$$ where $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^n$ when $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ or $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$. $|\alpha|=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\alpha_k$, $\alpha!=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\alpha_k!$, and $x^\alpha=\prod\limits_{k=1}^nx_k^{\alpha_k}$ Note that $$\frac{200!}{29!^6 26!}=\binom{200}{29}\binom{171}{29}\binom{142}{29}\binom{113}{29}\binom{84}{29}\binom{55}{29}$$